# android - how to cache an image from a remote site

Tags: android, caching

Can anyone please provide me some example on how to save an image i fetch from websites into a cache. I had try to include the following function into my code and call it once i run the activity.

> ```
> public void getRemoteImage(String imageUrl) {
>     imageUrl = "http://marga.mobile9.com/download/thumb/295/sexylady7_xo6npovn.jpg";
>       URL aURL = null;
>       URLConnection conn = null;
>       Bitmap bmp = null;
>       CacheResult cache_result = CacheManager.getCacheFile(imageUrl, new HashMap());
>       if (cache_result == null) {
>         try {
>             aURL = new URL(imageUrl);
>             conn = aURL.openConnection();
>             conn.connect();
>             InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
>             cache_result = new CacheManager.CacheResult();
>             CacheManager.saveCacheFile(imageUrl, cache_result);
>         } catch (Exception e) {
>             //return null;
>         }
>     }
>     bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cache_result.getInputStream());*/
>     Toast.makeText(context,"It works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     //return bmp;
> }
> ```

However, I got a nullPointerException. Can someone please help me with it as i'm quite new in android.

I got this from logcat :

```
06-17 19:07:51.291: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mobile9.android.gallery/mobile9.android.gallery.GalleryWallpapers}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2454)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.webkit.CacheManager.getCacheFile(CacheManager.java:296)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at mobile9.android.gallery.GalleryWallpapers.hahatest(GalleryWallpapers.java:558)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at mobile9.android.gallery.GalleryWallpapers.onCreate(GalleryWallpapers.java:132)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
06-17 19:07:51.301: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(464):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: First thing to do, would be to check the line of the exception and the provided exception details.

Comment: I had added the exception details on top. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use WebView? If you don't, I believe you can't use CacheManager. Refer to the following bug report for further details:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7222